# Hoeffding's inequality for error measures

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, inequality

When Hoeffding's inequality is used to justify that in sample error and out of sample error track each other, the error measure is simple mismatch -- there is no penalty associated with the different flavors of mismatch as in error measures. Specifically, for a binary classifier, the false-positives and false-negatives may not be treated identically (the user may want different penalties for both). Is there a version of Hoeffding which we could use with error measure as well? If so how does it look?